# Jquery ajax latency

Tags: jquery, underscore.js, latency

I am using jquery ajax as part of a instant search that shows results as you type.

I am using the debounce function from underscore.js to only send the request when the user has finished typing.

Everything works fine except there seems to be about 1.5s delay in showing the results first time round (checked network tab in dev tools). I have minimal code on the page that is requested, it is gziped and the MySQL queries return quickly (tested via db tool).

is there anything else I can do to speed this up?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: you need to check where the time is spent... on network or on server side